# java openssl X509_SIG structure and encode / decode functions

Tags: java, openssl, cryptography, x509

I'm trying to do in java a signature algorithm i've made in C that use the openssl C API `RSA_sign` function.
This function does not encrypt the data, but put the data into a `X509_SIG` structure with some metadata, encode the structure using `i2d_X509_SIG` openssl function and then finally encrypt the result of this encoding.
Is there a way to reproduce this way to sign data with Java ? Does `X509_SIG` struct and encoding / decoding functions exists in some java library ?
Yd

Answer (score 3):

You have misdescribed (or misunderstood) what `RSA_sign` does.

Ignoring some special cases not applicable here, it implements the RSA signature scheme originally defined in PKCS1 v1 as 'type 1', and now retained in PKCS1 v2 as RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 (i.e. the RSA Signature Scheme with Appendix from v1.5 of PKCS1); see [section 8.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-8.2) and [section 9.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-9.2) of rfc8017, plus the related primitives in [section 5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-5.2). To sign (or as the RFC states it more formally, to generate a signature) this effectively does the following, in order:

E1. hash the message

E2. encode the hash value plus an algorithm identifier for the hash algorithm as the ASN.1 structure DigestInfo in DER; because of the way DER works this is equivalent to adding a fixed prefix as described in the Notes to section 9.2.

E3-5. pad with 00 01 FF... (as needed but at least 8) 00

G2. convert the octet string to a number, apply the primitive RSASP1 which does modular exponentiation with the private exponent, and convert the (new) number back to an octet string of the correct size. Historically, a generation ago, this was sometimes described as 'encrypting with the private key', and RSAVP1 similarly as 'decrypting with the public key', even though this is semantically wrong because [signing is not encryption](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159282/can-openssl-decrypt-the-encrypted-signature-in-an-amazon-alexa-request/#159289), and it was soon discovered that this confusion led to bad system designs that were vulnerable and broken, so in this century we call them signing and verifying.

`RSA_sign` requires the caller to do do the hashing step (E1). It then calls `encode_pkcs1` to do step E2, using the name `X509_SIG` for the structure that is standardly called `DigestInfo`. It then calls `RSA_private_encrypt` which does E3-5 and G2; this naming is because OpenSSL descends from SSLeay which was written decades ago, when the confusion over 'signing is encryption backwards' was still common.

This signature scheme is (1) standard and (2) very common, and **is implemented in Java crypto** -- *including* the hashing step called for by the standard which differs from OpenSSL `RSA_sign`, *and* the DigestInfo step which is the same. See the `java.security.Signature` algorithm names (schemes) `{SHA1,SHA256,etc}withRSA` in https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#signature-algorithms .

Comment: Thanks a lot Dave for this complete answer. It will help me to go forward